# How to clear cookies in javascript without keeping any expiry time

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to clear cookies with out keeping any expiry time.

i have created a cookie like this

```
document.cookie = "visited=yes";
```

i need to remove this cookie.

How can i do that..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: document.cookie = 'visited=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

Comment: document.cookie = "visited=yes;expires=Fri, 31 Dec 1980 23:59:59 GMT;"

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would just update your cookies expiry time to delete it.

```
document.cookie = "expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
```

You can also write an empty cookie to reset it's values:

```
document.cookie = "key=";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp